# ng-container issue with "Error trying to diff..."

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I use Angular4 + PrimeNG. I need to not repeat template in my html file, so I decided to use `ng-container` to do so. However, when I use `ng-container` I'm getting an error:

> Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

How do I use `ng-container` with `*ngFor` clause properly to display the data inside nested `dataTable`? I cannot access this data, no matter what.

This is how the JSON looks like:

```
{
"status": 0,
"dallases": [{
    "vehicle_id": 17954,
    "dallassettings": "3",
    "dallasupdated": "False",
    "dallas_list": [{
        "number": 666111222,
        "auth": 3
    }, {
        "number": 666777888,
        "auth": 4
    }, {
        "number": 123454321,
        "auth": 4
    }]
}
}
```

**Service**

```
export class VehicleService {
    private defUrl = 'dummy.url';

constructor(private http: Http) { }
getVehicle(username?: string, password?: string) {
    const url = (!username || !password) ? this.defUrl : 'dummy.url' + username + '/' + Md5.hashStr(password);
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json());
```

**Component**

```
export class VehicleComponent implements OnInit {

  cols: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cols = [
      { field: 'vehicle_id', header: "Vehicle ID" },
      { field: 'dallassettings', header: 'Dallas settings' },
      { field: 'dallasupdated', header: 'Dallas updated' },
      { field: 'dallas_list', header: 'Dallas list' }
    ];

  public vehicles: GeneralVehicle[];

  constructor(private vehicleService: VehicleService, private router: Router) {
    this.vehicleService.getVehicle().subscribe(vehicle => {
      this.vehicles = vehicle;
    });
  }

interface GeneralVehicle {
  status: number;
  dallases: Vehicle[];
}

interface Vehicle {
  vehicle_id: number;
  dallassettings: string;
  dallasupdated: string;
  dallas_list: DallasList[];
}

interface DallasList {
  number: number;
  auth: number;
}
```

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="vehicles">
  <p-dataTable [value]="vehicles.dallases" expandableRows="true">
    <p-header>List of vehicles: <b>{{currentUser}}</b></p-header>
    <p-column expander="true" styleClass="col-icon"></p-column>
    <p-column field="vehicle_id" header="Vehicle ID" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="dallassettings" header="Dallas settings" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="dallasupdated" header="Dallas updated" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <ng-template let-vehicle pTemplate="rowexpansion">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let d of vehicles.dallas_list; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFunction">
        <p-dataTable [value]="d">
          <p-column field="number" header="Number" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
          <p-column field="auth" header="Auth" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        </p-dataTable>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
  </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create a `dataTable` with expandable rows, where when you expand the row, there's another `dataTable`, so user can manage data inside expanded row.

Everything is working fine until I click on expansion - at this point it returns an error.

Thanks

Comment: I don't the problem is because of `ng-container`. What is `vehicle.dallas_list`? Can you maybe create a plunker?

Comment: @Maximus I edited the question - added service and component. `vehicle.dallas_list` is a field in JSON, `dallas_list` contains `number` and `auth` fields which I want to put inside expandable row.

Comment: I don't see `vehicle.dallas_list` in the `JSON` you referenced

Comment: I made a typo, it's `vehicles.dallas_list`. I updated my code, now it doesn't return an error, when I expand the row, it's just blank space.

Comment: I'll need a plunker, can't help without it

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot create plunker, because I use api that is accessible only inside my workplace internet connection. If I rewrite the app for plunker, it won't run properly - no login possibility, blank JSONs etc.

Comment: is `dallas_list` an object, not array? this is what your `interface DallasList` says

Comment: `dallas_list` is an array of `Dallas_list` (interfaces) containing `number`s and `auth`s.

Comment: can you show the example of `dallas_list` object with data? what do you want to have in `d` in this `*ngFor="let d of vehicles.dallas_list;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some problems in your template, please check how your JSON looks like. There is no path such as:

```
vehicles.dallas_list
```

You do not need the `ng-container` here, just use the `vehicle` (which is referring to `let-vehicle` in `ng-template`) and use that in the inner `[value]`, to iterate `dallas_list`.

So your template should look like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="vehicles">
  <p-dataTable [value]="vehicles.dallases" expandableRows="true">
    <p-column expander="true" styleClass="col-icon"></p-column>
    <p-column field="vehicle_id" header="Vehicle ID" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="dallassettings" header="Dallas settings" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="dallasupdated" header="Dallas updated" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <ng-template let-vehicle pTemplate="rowexpansion">
        <p-dataTable [value]="vehicle.dallas_list">
          <p-column field="number" header="Number" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
          <p-column field="auth" header="Auth" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
        </p-dataTable>         
    </ng-template>
  </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

### [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QNGmBKB8cynNlimpgVGc?p=preview)

Comment: I made corrections and this is how it's looks like now: http://imgur.com/ImACe65 - sometimes no records founds, sometimes empty, tiny rows

Comment: Please fork the plunker with your code and json data and I'll take a look :)

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Z4WCFvCZAhrrGoLDby9s - added vehicles.json file. I copied the whole output for test user.

Comment: Updated answer and plunker. Seems to work fine now :)

Comment: I'm sure I did it before, but it didn't work. Either I misspelled something or you're a magician :) Thank you, again you're saving me. I wish I was 1% as good as you are haha :)

Comment: Hahhah, well, let's not exaggerate, I'm not that good :D :D But glad we got it sorted out! Have a great day and happy coding! :)